# client.UploadFile with FTP is not working

Tags: c#, windows, zebra-printers

Thanks in Advance.

Code is written to send a single file from windows server to printer. Printer is installed on windows server & able to give test print from notepad/WordPad. Addition to this, from windows server when I try to ping the printer IP address, I am able to ping the same. With this I already ensured that printer & windows server is able to make communication with each other.

Code:

```
try{
    using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.UploadFile("ftp://Printer IP/B1C_Data_XML92795.xml", System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, @"\\Server IP\LabelFiles\B1C_Data_XML92795.xml");
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    errormessage = ex.Message;
    errorstacktrace = ex.StackTrace;
}
```

This code is working on Windows Server A. When I moved this entire solution to Server B, on Server B, I am getting an below error:

errormessage
System error.

errorstacktrace
at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String method, String fileName) at Class_84780c95075c7d0edb28c9131871f01b._Execute_ed0d3090e0ce469ead03fea36f5fd832()

I am not able to point what is the exact cause of this problem. Requesting you to please help me to solve this problem.

I already tried to to perform FTP from both the servers & it is working fine. For this, I opened CMD & typed below command

C:\Windows\system32>ftp Printer IP
Connected to Printer IP.
220 ABR-79071 Version V75.20.14Z ready.

I already tried with

1. CMD commands
2. PING result
3. C drive to D drive file movement. But D drive to printer movement is not working on Server B. It is working on Server A. Both Servers A & B are identical. Only IP & hostnames are different.

I am expecting that someone will help me to solve this problem.

Comment: FYI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated : "_Starting in .NET 6, the WebRequest, **WebClient**, and ServicePoint classes **are deprecated**. The classes are still available, but they're not recommended for new development._"

Comment: Also quite relevant if your project targets .NET 6 or newer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/framework/network-programming/ftp "_For projects that target .NET 6 and later versions, **FTP is no longer supported**._"

Comment: In my case application supported version is: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 and 3.5 SP1

Comment: Hello Everyone,

Could you please help me in this case? I am not able to proceed further because of this blocker.